# Correlate two columns, sort of monitor ID #, and return vector listing correlations in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm very new to R and have hit a wall. I know some other folks have asked about this, but I'm trying to get my code to work, in hopes of trying to understand what's wrong -

```
The prompt is as follows: Write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between sulfate and nitrate for monitor locations where the number of completely observed cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement, then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0. A prototype of this function follows: 
        corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
            ## 'directory' is a character vector of length 1 indicating the location of
            ## the CSV files

            ## 'threshold' is a numeric vector of length 1 indicating the number of
            ## completely observed observations (on all variables) required to compute
            ## the correlation between nitrate and sulfate; the default is 0

            ## Return a numeric vector of correlations
```

**The code I've now sunk 9 hours in is as follows:**

```
            spectdata<- list.files(pattern= ".csv") #creates vector with list of filenames
            corr<-function(directory,threshold =0, id = 1:332){
            combined<-data.frame() #creates empty data frame
            output<-data.frame()
            output1<-data.frame()
              for(i in id){
                combined<-rbind(read.csv(directory[i], header=TRUE))
                output<-rbind(output,combined) #will open the CVS files and append the tables together 
                output1<-output[complete.cases(output), ] #??gets rid of NA in files
                sulfate<-output1["sulfate"] # ?? I think this will be a vector that is a subset of output1 that matches the "sulfate" column 
                nitrate<-output1["nitrate"]# ?? I think this will be a vector that is a subset of output1 that matches the "nitrate" column 

                }
             ok<-complete.cases(combined) #counts the number of complete cases
             if (threshold>= ok){ 
               correlation<-cor(data.frame(nitrate,sulfate))
               return(correlation)}
              else {
               print ("nothing!") }
        }
            cr<-corr(spectdata,threshold =150)     
            head(cr)

        **I'm getting:** 
                > cr<-corr(spectdata,threshold =150)     
                Warning message:
                In if (threshold >= ok) { :
                the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
               > head(cr)
                       nitrate    sulfate
            nitrate 1.00000000 0.06243369
            sulfate 0.06243369 1.00000000

    The answer for this particular problem where threshold = 150, should be: 
        source("corr.R")
        source("complete.R")
        cr <- corr("specdata", 150)
        head(cr)
         ## [1] -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.12350667 -0.07588814
   so it looks like the answer I have is completely wrong ha 
       Please feel free to provide any insight to 1) how to get a correctly sized vector, any other syntax or verbiage that might be helpful
```

Any and all help is great appreciated~

**I'm running in RStudio in Windows 10 on a PC.**

Comment: It's hard to see what is going on. Firstly, what happens when you remove rbind from `combined<-rbind(read.csv(directory[i], header=TRUE))` ?

Comment: A correlation between 2 vectors will be a single scalar value... If you are combining the dataframes you will get your 0.0624 value. But the actual output you are expecting is a vector... perhaps you are not supposed to combine the csv files but check the correlations for each individually?

Comment: And don't you mean `read.csv(spectdata[i])` instead of `read.csv[directory[I])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below please find a more legible code. I will be happy to answer any questions.

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  # set the working directory
  setwd(dir = directory)
  # creates vector of filenames within the directory
  spectdata <- list.files(pattern = ".csv") 
  # for each spectdata, read the sulfate and nitrate columns 
  L1 <- lapply(spectdata, function(x) read.csv(x, header = TRUE)[,c("sulfate","nitrate")])
  # for each csv that was read, removes rows that have NA
  L2 <- lapply(L1, function(x) x[complete.cases(x),])
  # removes csv from list if not greater than or are equal to the threshold
  L3 <- Filter(function(x) nrow(x) >= threshold, L2)
  # if the list still has a csv results after Filter (length of list > 0) then:
  if(length(L3) > 0) {
    # for each csv in list, calculate and save correlation between sulfare and nitrate
    Correlation <- lapply(L3, function(x) cor(x[,"sulfate"], x[,"nitrate"]))
    # change list output to a vector output
    unlist(Correlation) 
  } else {
    # return a zero length vector
    numeric(0)
  }
}

corr(directory = "C:/Users/Evan Friedland/Desktop/DIRECTORY", threshold = 100)
```

It looks a lot more concise without comments:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  setwd(dir = directory)
  spectdata <- list.files(pattern = ".csv") 
  L1 <- lapply(spectdata, function(x) read.csv(x, header = TRUE)[,c("sulfate","nitrate")])
  L2 <- lapply(L1, function(x) x[complete.cases(x),])
  L3 <- Filter(function(x) nrow(x) >= threshold, L2)
  if(length(L3) > 0) {
    Correlation <- lapply(L3, function(x) cor(x[,"sulfate"], x[,"nitrate"]))
    unlist(Correlation) 
  } else {
    numeric(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: ah I see - I haven't been able to input anything past the second if statement without running into errors about unexpected }...                I think not combining the files into one large data frame via the rbind function makes sense as each file itself corresponds to a monitor # (and there are 332 of them) - I believe we are to only include monitors that are above the threshold.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the syntax and functions included in the 
" if(length(combined > 0) {
    return(unlist(lapply(test, function(x) cor(x[,"sulfate"], x[,"nitrate"])))) "  -     I've not seen most of those words ~       also shouldn't combined be a data.frame()??  Thanks Evan! :)

Comment: Okay, if each csv is a monitor you are testing then use my second code block. so `if (length(combined > 0) {` is simply saying, okay, combined is a list, a list specifically of csv files that were greater than or equal to the threshold. `lapply(x, FUN)` is a function that applies another function (FUN) across each list. I know this syntax is a little advanced but I can supply a user-defined function for FUN. in this case I simply say, give me the `cor(sulfate, nitrate)` for each list element (or csv file).  let me know if that makes any sense. - and `unlist()` just turns list objects->vector

Comment: Give this a try: `L <- list(A = cbind(1,2), B = cbind(3,4)); L` and try `lapply(L, sum)` and then `unlist(lapply(L, sum))`. This is the same as the nastier user-defined function method `lapply(L, function(i) i[1] + i[2])` where `i` is the variable that represents each element in the list.

Comment: ah - okay thanks for the explanation. I'm trying to run the first set of code you commented (with the lapply), and keep running errors with the brackets - did you get it to run on your machine? :/

Comment: I cant actually run any code because i have no csv files to test. I dont know what anything looks like (based on the info you gave me) so everything is a guess xD what specifically is the error

Comment: Most are related to the brackets :                              +   if(length(combined > 0) {
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"  }
  if(length(combined > 0) {"
>     return(unlist(lapply(test, function(x) cor(x[,"sulfate"], x[,"nitrate"]))))
Error in lapply(test, function(x) cor(x[, "sulfate"], x[, "nitrate"])) : 
  object 'test' not found
>   } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>     return(numeric(0))
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>

Comment: I'd be down to move platforms, but SO won't let me chat you because I don't have enough points :P

Comment: Yes I tried out chatting you at one point but the points issue~ do me a favor, read one single csv file and paste me the str(x) output? so I can see the structure and make myself a fake example to test

Comment: Here's the str(x) of the first (of 332) CSV files - > str(x)
'data.frame': 1461 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date   : Factor w/ 1461 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ sulfate: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ nitrate: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ID     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

Comment: The first several rows are NA's, and later there are actual readings from the monitors - thanks again :D

Comment: See my edit- and then if it works I can re-edit the answer to be just that :)  The only thing is that you cannot tell which monitor the correlation is from... is this something you need?

Comment: Nope, don't need to know which monitors are above the threshold, just their correlations - but there's an error:  Error in cor(x[, "sulfate"], x[, "nitrate"], use = "complete.obs") : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x' "

Comment: Hmm... you see where it says combined[[i]] <- NULL... try making that combined[i] <- NULL instead

Comment: omg it was just formatting, make that big function all on the same line, sorry-- see edits

Comment: I can try this when I get home later hmm - did it end up working for you (with the updated code, the third one down in the answer?) you rock btw :P

Comment: Giving it a go, will post it soon. My pleasure, always love a good challenge

Comment: It works! :) For a coursera, part of the data science specialization (which I suggest, but sounds like you've already got most of the skills down :P) - I've got a couple questions though : 1) what does "[,c("sulfate","nitrate")]" do in the first line of the for loop?, 2) did you specify any packages or libraries? I'm unfamiliar with the "Filter function" and the "{ } "syntax in that line, 3) I'm confused on the series of functions used in the "unlist(lapply(L, function(x) cor(x[,"sulfate"], x[,"nitrate"], use = "complete.obs")))"  hmmm but feel free to ignore this, you've done enough :P

Comment: 1) subsets (trims) the data.frame by column name to only those 2. I am noticing some of the subsetting is repetitive now but can't change until tomorrow XD. 2) zero packages- i like sticking with base R. I suggest googling Filter. Just let me cut out elements in the lists that didnt meat the threshold. The squiggly brackets contain a function code block. I just put it in 1 line. 3) i have a comment up here somewhere explaining lapply and unlist

Comment: Glad to have helped. If this satisfies you answer and you'd like to mark you question as solved, please use the check mark next to my answer~